# Read in data from a text file in Matlab that is not delimited in a consistent manner

Tags: python, perl, matlab, filereader

I have a text file that contains data that is printed in a manner suitable for viewing but not for processing programmatically. This is because it uses white space as a delimiter and there are blank entries in a row but no way that I can think of to distinguish them. That is why I am submitting a question here.

Example File Contents:

```
              Bend Machine Information
              ========================

Bend #      Offset      Twist Angle     Bend Angle    Bend Radius
-------- -------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- 
   1             147.17                         13.39          31.75  
   2             116.11         180.00          13.39          31.75  
   3             199.92         305.13          90.00          31.75  
   4               0.10           0.00          90.00          31.75  
   5              68.75
```

End of File.

So in the above text there is no entry in the Twist Angle column for the first row but the whitespace does not indicate that.

Any ideas on how to parse this? 
I would like to use Matlab but another language is possible (like Perl or Python).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In full script mode, the logic could be done using perl as follows:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    next if $. < 6;
    my @vals = $_ =~ /(.{8})(.{15})(.{15})(.{15})(.{15})/;
    s/\s//g for @vals;
    print join(',', @vals), "\n";
}

__DATA__
              Bend Machine Information
              ========================

Bend #      Offset      Twist Angle     Bend Angle    Bend Radius
-------- -------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- 
   1             147.17                         13.39          31.75  
   2             116.11         180.00          13.39          31.75  
   3             199.92         305.13          90.00          31.75  
   4               0.10           0.00          90.00          31.75  
   5              68.75
```

Or turned into a one liner:

```
perl -nle 'next if $.<6; @v=$_=~/(.{8})(.{15})(.{15})(.{15})(.{15})/; s/\s//g for @v; print join(",", @v)' your_file
```

Outputs:

```
1,147.17,,13.39,31.75
2,116.11,180.00,13.39,31.75
3,199.92,305.13,90.00,31.75
4,0.10,0.00,90.00,31.75
5,68.75,,,
```

A nicer approach might be to insert a comma at the space between sections.  That way the file still stays readable.

```
perl -pe 'if ($.>5){for $i(8,23,38,53){substr $_,$i,1,","}}' your_file
```

Outputs:

```
              Bend Machine Information
              ========================

Bend #      Offset      Twist Angle     Bend Angle    Bend Radius
-------- -------------- -------------- -------------- --------------
   1    ,        147.17,              ,         13.39,         31.75
   2    ,        116.11,        180.00,         13.39,         31.75
   3    ,        199.92,        305.13,         90.00,         31.75
   4    ,          0.10,          0.00,         90.00,         31.75
   5    ,         68.75,              ,              ,
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Matlab answer.  I think @Miller's regex is smarter than mine and automatically identifies the missing field - if you can read Perl regex, you can probably implement it in Matlab using the technique below.

The first block reads the entire file into a cell array, without trying to read via a format string.  There's probably a faster way to do it.

The second block skips the header rows, then goes through row-by-row to match a regular expression against the row.  See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html

The expression I have says to match to '0 or more spaces, 1 or more digits, 0 or 1 ., 0 more digits, 0 or more spaces'.  That should grab all the numbers and put them in a cell array.

If only one data column is missing, then it's easy to rearrange the cell array into the array you want.  Otherwise, switch the `regexp()` to `regexp(file{k}, pattern, 'tokens', 'tokenExtents')`, and used the returned indices to figure out what was grabbed (and hence what is missing).  Obviously, I'm overwriting the results with each line, in practice you'll either want to process this this in the loop and save out to a results array or save the tokens and extents from each loop iteration in array to process later.

```
fid = fopen(<filepath>);
% The following method is slow but works
file = [];
k = 1;
tline = fgetl(fid);
while ischar(tline)
    file{k} = tline;
    tline = fgetl(fid);
    k = k+1;
end
fclose(fid);

header_rows = 5;
pattern = '\s*(\d+\.?\d*)\s*';

% Start at the first non-header row and go to the end
for k = (header_rows+1):length(file)
     tokens = regexp(file{k}, pattern, 'tokens');
     tokens{1,:}
end
```